# How do I start e new note in Evernote with the cursor in the title instead of the body of the note?

Tags: windows, evernote

When using Evernote on Windoes the default starting field is the body of the document.  While the first line of the body becomes the title, I prefer to have my title not part of the body. I also would prefer not to start a new note then have to click every time to the title field.

Answer (score 4):

There are at least two possible options for solving this.  One method is to use the shortcut <kbd>F2</kbd> (on a Mac running Bootcamp you might use <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>) after you start a new note.  However, if this shortcut is not acceptable you can make the following registry change:

```
Key location: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Evernote\Evernote
Key Name: SetNewNoteFocusToTitle
Values: 0/1 Default: 0
Comments: Make the title focused when creating a new note.
```

This information is also scattered around [this](http://discussion.evernote.com/topic/33492-new-note-not-starting-on-title-and-other-option-settings/) post